# React Destructuring with propTypes

Tags: reactjs, react-proptypes

I am facing some issues when I tried to do validation with propTypes:

```js
class MediaBrowse extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { name, age, array } = this.props.data;
    return (<div></div>)
  }
}
```

And I gave propTypes validation as:

```js
MediaBrowse.PropTypes = {
  name: PropTypes.string,
  age: PropTypes.number,
  array: PropTypes.array
};
```

But it is saying when I run eslint validation as `data.name` is missing in props validation.
Same for all..

From parent component I passed data like 
Can anyone help to resolve this?

Comment: your `propTypes` expects `this.props.name` but you are trying extract `this.props.data.name` - which is it that you want?

Comment: use `propTypes` (camel case)

Comment: its not working for for trigger functions.. its saying function is missing in props function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
const { name, age, array} = this.props.data
```

You do not define `props.data` anywhere, so it is `undefined`.

Change `MediaBrowse.PropTypes` to `MediaBrowse.propTypes` (lowercase "p"):

```
MediaBrowse.propTypes = {
  name: PropTypes.string,
  age: PropTypes.number,
  array: PropTypes.array,
}
```

When you define props, they are accessible inside the `props` object like so:

```
const { name, age, array } = this.props
```

---

UPDATE:

Your function can be defined with `propTypes` like so:

```
MediaBrowse.propTypes = {
  // add this to your existing propTypes
  onSearchText: PropTypes.func,
}
```

And if you want to define a default function, you can define it like so:

```
MediaBrowse.defaultProps = {
  // define the params and return type of your function here
  // I have just used this as an example
  onSearchText: () => void
}
```

Comment: but i am also facing some issue with function. onChange={(e) => this.props.onSearchText(e.target.value)} I had given like this MediaBrowse.propTypes ={ data: PropTypes.shape({ onSearchText:PropTypes.func }) } But still its saying onSearchText is missing in props function

Comment: @midhun k I have updated my answer. Does this solve your question or are you still experiencing issues?

Answer (score 2):

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'

MediaBrowse.propTypes ={
      data: PropTypes.shape({
        name: PropTypes.string,
        age: PropTypes.number,
        array: PropTypes.array,
     })
    }
```

Comment: but i am also facing some issue with function.
 onChange={(e) => this.props.onSearchText(e.target.value)}
I had given like this
MediaBrowse.propTypes ={
      data: PropTypes.shape({
onSearchText:PropTypes.func
})
}
But still its saying onSearchText is missing in props function

Comment: Please run `console.log(this.props)` and update your original question with the output of that. I will then update my answer.